# Auto formatting ES6 destructuring assignment in IntelliJ/WebStorm

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I'm utilizing the airbnb eslint rules for linting my ES6 code. One of the rules forces `object-curly-spacing`.

An example of the rule, using destructuring assignment in a function, is as follows:

**Bad:**

```
function({a, b}) {

}
```

**Good**:

```
function({ a, b }) {

}
```

I would really like Intellij/WebStorm to automatically insert these spaces when I reformat code, however, none of the `Codestyle` settings seem to affect destructuring. The closest codestyle setting I could find is `Object Literal Braces` but it has no effect.

Shy of turning off this rule, is there any additional setting, plugin, etc that would automatically insert spaces before and after around destructuring assignments?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16776 and related, I guess.

Comment: Please also try WebStorm v12 -- there were some changes (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19645) so maybe there was another ticket that does what you want already.

Comment: in WS 12EAP "Object Literal Braces" covers destructuring objects

Comment: Just tried 12EAP and indeed, works. How about IntelliJ IDEA? 16EAP?

Comment: yes, IDEA 16 EAP includes all features WS12  EAP

Comment: @anstarovoyt Is there any support of this in IDEA 15?

Comment: @AbhinavSingi unfortunately no

Answer (score 33):

As mentioned in the comments this option exist in later versions of webstorm/intellij. I was having a hard time finding them so here is a picture of where to find them:

[image]

Comment: This does not work for destructuring `{foo,bar} = it` which is reported for object-curly-spacing

Comment: Did anyone get a fix for this? I am still struggling.

Comment: As of today, I still don't see an option in the latest version of WebStorm. I've even set my rules based on ESLint, which requires the spacing. When I use WebStorm to fix for the "prefer-destructuring" rule, it causes the "object-curly-spacing" error...